# Ansible, HP-UX, ImportError: Failed to load /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/binascii.sl

Tags: python-2.7, ansible, hp-ux

Trying run ansible ping on HP-UX host, but receive python error. All librarys and priveleges is OK.

ansible -vvvv -i ./servers all -m ping

output

```
<infappr> PUT /tmp/tmpxQfBr5 TO //.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1471342470.57-207842142718136/ping
<infappr> SSH: EXEC sftp -b - -C -vvv 
-o ControlMaster=auto 
-o ControlPersist=60s 
-o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no 
-o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey 
-o PasswordAuthentication=no 
-o ConnectTimeout=10 
-o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r '[infappr]'
<infappr> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
<infappr> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -vvv 
-o ControlMaster=auto 
-o ControlPersist=60s 
-o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no 
-o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey 
-o PasswordAuthentication=no 
-o ConnectTimeout=10 
-o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r 
-tt infappr '/bin/sh -c '"'"'LANG=POSIX LC_ALL=POSIX LC_MESSAGES=POSIX /usr/bin/python //.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1471342470.57-207842142718136/ping; rm -rf "//.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1471342470.57-207842142718136/" > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'"'"''

OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 0.9.8j-fips 07 Jan 2009
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4
debug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote
debug3: mux_client_request_session: entering
debug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering
debug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 14572
debug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent
debug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2
debug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe
debug2: Received exit status from master 0
Shared connection to infappr closed.

    "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1471342470.57-207842142718136/ping", line 6, in <module>
    import base64
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/base64.py", line 11, in <module>
    import binascii
ImportError: Failed to load /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/binascii.sl
```

Some more details.

Client host

```
# uname -a
HP-UX infappr B.11.31 U 9000/800
# ll /usr/local/lib/python2.7|grep "lib-dynload"
drwxr-xr-x 2 root sys  8192 Aug 16 12:19 lib-dynload
# ll /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/binascii.sl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root sys 32768 Jun 28 16:06 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/binascii.sl
```

Some more details.Some more details.Some more details.Some more details.Some more details.Some more details.Some more details.Some more details.Some more details.Some more details.Some more details.Some more details.Some more details.Some more details.Some more details.Some more details.

I don't know other details!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Problem in required shared library

```
# ldd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/binascii.sl
        /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.sl =>       /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.sl
        /usr/lib/libm.2 =>      /usr/lib/libm.2
        /usr/lib/libdld.2 =>    /usr/lib/libdld.2
        /usr/lib/libc.2 =>      /usr/lib/libc.2
        /usr/lib/libdld.2 =>    /usr/lib/libdld.2
        /usr/lib/librt.2 =>     /usr/lib/librt.2
        /usr/lib/libnsl.1 =>    /usr/lib/libnsl.1
        /usr/lib/libxti.2 =>    /usr/lib/libxti.2
        /usr/lib/libc.2 =>      /usr/lib/libc.2
/usr/lib/dld.sl: Can't find path for shared library: libz.sl
/usr/lib/dld.sl: No such file or directory
```

Library download path http://hpux.connect.org.uk/hppd/hpux/Misc/zlib-1.2.8/